# MTOM messages must have type 'application/xop+xml'

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-extensions

I'm using C# to call a Java Webservice.  Fiddler gives me a status of 200. So my call to the service is good.  But something in the .NET does not like my MTOM message.  Any ideas?  Here are all the details.

I'm getting this error:

```
MTOM messages must have type 'application/xop+xml'.
```

The stack trace says:

```
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MtomMessageEncoder.MtomBufferedMessageData.TakeXmlReader()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageData.GetMessageReader()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage..ctor(IBufferedMessageData messageData, RecycledMessageState recycledMessageState, Boolean[] understoodHeaders, Boolean understoodHeadersModified)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MtomMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, String contentType)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.DecodeBufferedMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, Stream inputStream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadBufferedMessage(Stream inputStream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, Exception& requestException)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at ESARWS.ESAR.CORETransaction.COREEnvelopeBatchSubmission(COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionRequest request)
   at ESARWS.ESAR.CORETransactionClient.ESARWS.ESAR.CORETransaction.COREEnvelopeBatchSubmission(COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionRequest request) in C:\Project\xxxWS\Service References\ESAR\Reference.cs:line 665
   at ESARWS.ESAR.CORETransactionClient.COREEnvelopeBatchSubmission(String& PayloadType, String& ProcessingMode, String& PayloadID, String PayloadLength, String& TimeStamp, String& SenderID, String& ReceiverID, String& CORERuleVersion, String& CheckSum, String Payload, Byte[]& Payload1, String& ErrorCode, String& ErrorMessage) in  C:\Project\xxxWS\Service References\ESAR\Reference.cs:line 681
   at ESARWS.ESAR278Operations.BatchSubmission() in C:\Project\xxxxOperations.cs:line 102
```

The text response from fiddler says this:

```
--MIMEBoundary_79a945e87ba858f448c98d77b4a80ffb5d7e70ea4b3491dd
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <0.69a945e87ba858f448c98d77b4a80ffb5d7e70ea4b3491dd@apache.org>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><s:Header><VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPoxsRrdQam4pCh9xnvaklXQ8AAAAAOsbNCp3TVE2fafQwhTHlfYnD2y/Y1ylFtm6h6if1ZaUACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData><o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1"><o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="x509bst_24" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-bc"></enc:EncryptionMethod><enc:CipherData><enc:CipherValue>2VTxiub+ACsIUXe9zfgKBCfSeWB4/nfWYJ1nGo1rbKsHk2hVyYpL++V6ZmhzSKKvBuE55PmKipFTTheXUsYsnRRL/eTfwKK1tZsOxHPMQYdROChHnLfd7/TkymKxlVHtqs+OYp/d5JFjCSR<enc:CipherValue>ZuXZnEjQ+zcAjUQfobfk5s1CscqJ5CEu8Bpjxa/iaF/GLf44E+xRR++Jp96A0Oktp/iJC88cvjfPejj8/6oaOWQxwHBPKPvzjG3QlnuO5jqxhU4P7SlD1MlxB+b2gYCGCD0tDaNG0/Xji7IhEsJUXsbKBTHYyK1KsprVZodo+jJlWJ/WGby7JLsrp2dqf4henH5SS4LjPzHww5SDzZB59KoHRny1mjzuBaIhlXZi8EBCMxRlH1FaRNJ+ekQVDrore8MfJVlKGwGjlF8miUwxsIr3SMKekd1Xh3gMQ2BZ6h9sNRejTDuPTzZqbL4In0e6Dtfh9+7r8d2WbARtRAR/7j3ZiR+awgan6CdWXU73TUQ2mK10IS+WXDKs96VIIahhRqCS1fMZZdqthyYfJ6xQLWFECxorlXhZA+/MQgg25w2umraiR4lcQ1M/VXCTmnl1UDvP2ygD+Kvq2g/8mL+ZPJ6Wi/OCPEoe6olm0kRjkjComfeByypKVRfI6ht3gdf5rDyNJuXZ3UTjS8VNpJmN0V04gn9ZAQZThNnx3Oe+Xd+0F30EombtHkRLxPgxv+zn3NwDiUv175bvJ5HSeTtcFcoJ2slVnf7tO8im4Hd0eRd61suJr9qtxHJ/Wc/VCr6xEfEGuTHCgUGRwfqyo5ZjGICoSKmUWt+cDJFRDBLlqj5BacbTm1fJlr36mFsrVWvHh3ufRrguSDrCBirtfUBU3Gv/TsL+tc9so0tTbCYoXQB2JrEDFIcvX0fr9Vpqe3duwEsryVgKeUGGPflMFDEdY9TPXJjgGKcssG0D2RsJ7DCi3flSVGyCOkgfXfBgJcgIOHfuHCeg4eYe72hSLhZ6RXC8MxCS3SFay8ILY8kw/ampgwbLL2R8sjul/woCsTLH4q/rTLnXqCa0efoXxizcfsWr2RJnC9W85oAnwPwNS9g8qxiCZj6iEqxcCod/ZdA0</enc:CipherValue></enc:CipherData></enc:EncryptedData></s:Body></s:Envelope>
--MIMEBoundary_79a945e87ba858f448c98d77b4a80ffb5d7e70ea4b3491dd
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="application/soap+xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><s:Header><VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPoxsRrdQam4pCh9xnvaklXQ8AAAAAOsbNCp3TVE2fafQwhTHlfYnD2y/Y1ylFtm6h6if1ZaUACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData><o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-dd547292-aaba-4d74-979c-c9a3359907d9-1"><u:Created>2018-03-29T17:29:04.685Z</u:Created><u:Expires>2018-03-29T17:34:04.685Z</u:Expires></u:Timestamp><o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-5e4e7a78-9a34-4162-a428-e004ecf40ab2-2" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"><xop:Include href="cid:http://tempuri.org/1/636579161448284066" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/></o:BinarySecurityToken><e:EncryptedKey Id="_0" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/></e:EncryptionMethod><KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><o:SecurityTokenReference><o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509SubjectKeyIdentifier" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">j0ZKFBmTz3Kj0cQ82rq63MYAR+0=</o:KeyIdentifier></o:SecurityTokenReference></KeyInfo><e:CipherData><e:CipherValue>cnuxTT+iDwO1QEVeJzGexQ9oD5FDA89Q3vYQh6t9riAZa3yqKQFge2MqwWqpMWhEcVlzVuyGZPubCc1dRC1hihN1bVuteSL/PA691j43y9DAGqkEd0azMvbV6dPXTt9JqzNAjwCIEyJWUk4ROolRsODJpPGtLP+e0xiKozzxzEcK+7V8V5/oPB9l32SNR3guFuB2aaiS3WYno7vO3O7Caz7zixwaJAkt+ID7R9TNkUWS0zzASZlkSrA8KJlxXPIQgg9OPlMXARBC6FAYww/451lVGzfOf5YDgUNun+K63njHdavjv+SVMit4PLKncpAz+sEQNOY7CjhE3rqQwr4GCA==</e:CipherValue></e:CipherData><e:ReferenceList><e:DataReference URI="#_2"/><e:DataReference URI="#_3"/></e:ReferenceList></e:EncryptedKey><e:EncryptedData Id="_3" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/><e:CipherData><e:CipherValue><xop:Include href="cid:http://tempuri.org/2/636579161448324212" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/></e:CipherValue></e:CipherData></e:EncryptedData></o:Security></s:Header><s:Body u:Id="_1"><e:EncryptedData Id="_2" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/><e:CipherData><e:CipherValue>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</e:CipherValue></e:CipherData></e:EncryptedData></s:Body></s:Envelope>
--MIMEBoundary_79a945e87ba858f448c98d77b4a80ffb5d7e70ea4b3491dd
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/1/636579161448284066>

0  0  !k 9 < ? U ~0
    * H
```

The raw response from fiddler says this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 29 Mar 2018 17:29:05 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
$WSSP: 443
$WSCS: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
MIME-Version: 1.0
Host: cmsprovider.cahwnet.gov
$WSXCTCONTEXTID: ddnLe4a6yksA2wDmR7cAAABx
$WSSN: cmsprovider.cahwnet.gov
$WSSI: mqZpzAd48yfwCOnOLIRvFsOJcGVwpTEBbE9DdjdIZDU=
$WSRH: 10.186.112.31
$WSSC: https
$WSIS: true
Surrogate-Capability: WS-ESI="ESI/1.0+"
$WSRA: 10.186.112.31
Expect: 100-continue
_WS_HAPRT_WLMVERSION: -1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Forwarded-For: 107.140.0.90
$WSPR: HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 24061
Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="MIMEBoundary_79a945e87ba858f448c98d77b4a80ffb5d7e70ea4b3491dd"; type="application/soap+xml"; start="<0.69a945e87ba858f448c98d77b4a80ffb5d7e70ea4b3491dd@apache.org>"; action="http://interfaces.services.dhcs.ca.gov/CORETransaction/COREEnvelopeBatchSubmissionResponse"
Content-Encoding: 
Content-Language: en-US
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age= 31536000
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN

--MIMEBoundary_79a945e87ba858f448c98d77b4a80ffb5d7e70ea4b3491dd
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <0.69a945e87ba858f448c98d77b4a80ffb5d7e70ea4b3491dd@apache.org>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><s:Header><VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPoxsRrdQam4pCh9xnvaklXQ8AAAAAOsbNCp3TVE2fafQwhTHlfYnD2y/Y1ylFtm6h6if1ZaUACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData><o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1"><o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="x509bst_24" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-" Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod></enc:EncryptionMethod><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><o:SecurityTokenReference><o:Reference URI="#x509bst_24" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"></o:Reference></o:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo><enc:CipherData><enc:CipherValue>IHbdP4qSEJddE+oPn4MD0hlmhgOzm+4napoWcXpXzESMNwZkNUd2CyH+r0PXayvfUvU9fYj0vBnG5oJGzyJxyyF7Dkqy/bqUVo4myjBj2CudUigjJnOT1urz/0F9Kr9+v6U+oV3MfYKrKzb2COuco0qMBT70Y83s5BXV3l6JTi6IABDDzJpK7bMq2XW9+VGQ+xb1kv+id3iqWr2G2Oa/qGbXIDZQucJKj5pZPVGKui6oo+n7CkOC9MWtRxKcKxsvEaFTIXHqQAh14imsB+kcYmyg6y7qWbTuiiBmbjWkW5CnjQNPRYRz1fjmf63LCfvu0lZu+WUPQm/2NZrfs/6VMg==</enc:CipherValue></enc:CipherData><enc:ReferenceList><enc:DataReference URI="#wssecurity_encryption_id_22"></enc:DataReference><enc:DataReference URI="#wssecurity_encryption_id_23"></enc:DataReference></enc:ReferenceList></enc:EncryptedKey><enc:EncryptedData xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="wssecurity_encryption_id_23" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"><enc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"></enc:EncryptionMethod><enc:CipherData><enc:CipherValue>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</enc:CipherValue></enc:CipherData></enc:EncryptedData><u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-dd547292-aaba-4d74-979c-c9a3359907d9-1"><u:Created>2018-03-29T17:29:04.685Z</u:Created><u:Expires>2018-03-29T17:34:04.685Z</u:Expires></u:Timestamp><o:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" u:Id="uuid-5e4e7a78-9a34-4162-a428-e004ecf40ab2-2">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</o:BinarySecurityToken><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="u s o ds "></ec:InclusiveNamespaces></ds:CanonicalizationMethod><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></ds:SignatureMethod><ds:Reference URI="#wssecurity_sigconf_id_20"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="u s o wsse11 wsu "></ec:InclusiveNamespaces></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod><ds:DigestValue>bl7AQkFZ5cTPILAHFp+GF0UYyYg=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference><ds:Reference URI="#_1"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="u s i #default "></ec:InclusiveNamespaces></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod><ds:DigestValue>WrjOtxXRuZnQVkNtcE/Ol3Zlby8=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>Koma0Xhfp0EdKXKjk4IXKpQF81IpwQemGkb9KOCV9XZsJDZ3Sx/LeUGEG4R3detuopridaCHBl2fzKkPgJtqfTk3CwVP53gWbj4f3YmNlT8iWzLCskQRpBsl8Y/0vla8FZv28QQERg1t32Hs2LgEm6rBTnvRu2Q1R8ZgEEqmZkFVMj7H38BH8G/krqyIku0wjXenpIL3u2F3Ko2iZRc7D7qr3x6AAjEUMClOWOBsR0ey7XQHQcp3nsspkly65HGcCeEkD2r9MEIVEvDpg0nvNtQavsRtzww5MMdLkzQPfVyanxEEHn+1va477qxQwxJrumC2Gq+24Ip0sR4/ciIRNw==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><o:SecurityTokenReference><o:Reference URI="#x509bst_21" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"></o:Reference></o:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature><e:EncryptedKey xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="_0"><e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"><DigestMethod xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></DigestMethod></e:EncryptionMethod><KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><o:SecurityTokenReference><o:KeyIdentifier EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509SubjectKeyIdentifier">j0ZKFBmTz3Kj0cQ82rq63MYAR+0=</o:KeyIdentifier></o:SecurityTokenReference></KeyInfo><e:CipherData><e:CipherValue>cnuxTT+iDwO1QEVeJzGexQ9oD5FDA89Q3vYQh6t9riAZa3yqKQFge2MqwWqpMWhEcVlzVuyGZPubCc1dRC1hihN1bVuteSL/PA691j43y9DAGqkEd0azMvbV6dPXTt9JqzNAjwCIEyJWUk4ROolRsODJpPGtLP+e0xiKozzxzEcK+7V8V5/oPB9l32SNR3guFuB2aaiS3WYno7vO3O7Caz7zixwaJAkt+ID7R9TNkUWS0zzASZlkSrA8KJlxXPIQgg9OPlMXARBC6FAYww/451lVGzfOf5YDgUNun+K63njHdavjv+SVMit4PLKncpAz+sEQNOY7CjhE3rqQwr4GCA==</e:CipherValue></e:CipherData><e:ReferenceList><e:DataReference URI="#_2"></e:DataReference><e:DataReference URI="#_3"></e:DataReference></e:ReferenceList></e:EncryptedKey><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></CanonicalizationMethod><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></SignatureMethod><Reference URI="#_1"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></DigestMethod><DigestValue>AwssDd3r2f/yalXQqjuVNtobYEE=</DigestValue></Reference><Reference URI="#uuid-dd547292-aaba-4d74-979c-c9a3359907d9-1"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></DigestMethod><DigestValue>DnRZFvMeGWbXIFZC9eazceOKQNY=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>XKc+NAH/icmpLv3aLua6eP73P0gn40okPbVDivaR0RPVjKpOfEk798U+VYK/oKDesZ4JSknrfegqXn+U8gh0ci9cXngQ+8OghsoGQ2ve0gZIIWEWwBL4N9RdNYp6uaQoDYr3356rJ16teyIgxsmQNv7NkdqPVdCgtJcAXFguyte89cnAvfxWQxh3R2/D9uEBw6rLbRPMBcaVh+y1yj2V+GMnnhKiLPoU7qm6H1kJIdYfiWBvorSsGPGiPpFINliWVSg1KwpzJHNRa7eg8pqAqxSdKyF5ytCZBH/R08+/qIbC+zvXDnDPTLds8cOBwHZJ8oXhFDqTAuaDattaX6dwkA==</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><o:SecurityTokenReference><o:Reference URI="#uuid-5e4e7a78-9a34-4162-a428-e004ecf40ab2-2" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"></o:Reference></o:SecurityTokenReference></KeyInfo></Signature></o:Security></s:Header><s:Body u:Id="_1"><enc:EncryptedData xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="wssecurity_encryption_id_22" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content"><enc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"></enc:EncryptionMethod><enc:CipherData><enc:CipherValue>ZuXZnEjQ+zcAjUQfobfk5s1CscqJ5CEu8Bpjxa/iaF/GLf44E+xRR++Jp96A0Oknf7tO8im4Hd0eRd61suJr9qtxHJ/Wc/VCr6xEfEGuTHCgUGRwfqyo5ZjGICoSKmUWt+cDJFRDBLlqj5BacbTm1fJlr36mFsrVWvHh3ufRrguSDrCBirtfUBU3Gv/TsL+tc9so0tTbCYoXQB2JrEDFIcvX0fr9Vpqe3duwEsryVgKeUGGPflMFDEdY9TPXJjgGKcssG0D2RsJ7DCi3flSVGyCOkgfXfBgJcgIOHfuHCeg4eYe72hSLhZ6RXC8MxCS3SFay8ILY8kw/ampgwbLL2R8sjul/woCsTLH4q/rTLnXqCa0efoXxizcfsWr2RJnC9W85oAnwPwNS9g8qxiCZj6iEqxcCod/ZdA0</enc:CipherValue></enc:CipherData></enc:EncryptedData></s:Body></s:Envelope>
--MIMEBoundary_79a945e87ba858f448c98d77b4a80ffb5d7e70ea4b3491dd
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="application/soap+xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><s:Header><VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPoxsRrdQam4pCh9xnvaklXQ8AAAAAOsbNCp3TVE2fafQwhTHlfYnD2y/Y1ylFtm6h6if1ZaUACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData><o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-dd547292-aaba-4d74-979c-c9a3359907d9-1"><u:Created>2018-03-29T17:29:04.685Z</u:Created><u:Expires>2018-03-29T17:34:04.685Z</u:Expires></u:Timestamp><o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-5e4e7a78-9a34-4162-a428-e004ecf40ab2-2" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"><xop:Include href="cid:http://tempuri.org/1/636579161448284066" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/></o:BinarySecurityToken><e:EncryptedKey Id="_0" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/></e:EncryptionMethod><KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><o:SecurityTokenReference><o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509SubjectKeyIdentifier" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">j0ZKFBmTz3Kj0cQ82rq63MYAR+0=</o:KeyIdentifier></o:SecurityTokenReference></KeyInfo><e:CipherData><e:CipherValue>cnuxTT+iDwO1QEVeJzGexQ9oD5FDA89Q3vYQh6t9riAZa3yqKQFge2MqwWqpMWhEcVlzVuyGZPubCc1dRC1hihN1bVuteSL/PA691j43y9DAGqkEd0azMvbV6dPXTt9JqzNAjwCIEyJWUk4ROolRsODJpPGtLP+e0xiKozzxzEcK+7V8V5/oPB9l32SNR3guFuB2aaiS3WYno7vO3O7Caz7zixwaJAkt+ID7R9TNkUWS0zzASZlkSrA8KJlxXPIQgg9OPlMXARBC6FAYww/451lVGzfOf5YDgUNun+K63njHdavjv+SVMit4PLKncpAz+sEQNOY7CjhE3rqQwr4GCA==</e:CipherValue></e:CipherData><e:ReferenceList><e:DataReference URI="#_2"/><e:DataReference URI="#_3"/></e:ReferenceList></e:EncryptedKey><e:EncryptedData Id="_3" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/><e:CipherData><e:CipherValue><xop:Include href="cid:http://tempuri.org/2/636579161448324212" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/></e:CipherValue></e:CipherData></e:EncryptedData></o:Security></s:Header><s:Body u:Id="_1"><e:EncryptedData Id="_2" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/><e:CipherData><e:CipherValue>x7uF7/QweCOy1Y5+MkcXhHWFwZEF6+8Xa6Bw2iPQPmcNKNQco5Rzv/xNjQVk6q5PzSgvzn4pfGiXJsawMfEy3+t9312b3b9VWWgWa2</e:CipherValue></e:CipherData></e:EncryptedData></s:Body></s:Envelope>
--MIMEBoundary_79a945e87ba858f448c98d77b4a80ffb5d7e70ea4b3491dd
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/1/636579161448284066>

0  0  !k 9 < ? U ~0
B   ͹ D   O$" p` 2϶l $ S G= "s1 1\K(  0 K k i   
)Q 6   x;   $ JKmg '  \ 3      ا     A    l  F  Ew l Y*:L  , K  L ٞ * ̟ ) t7,L  r՛ JY I ,
--MIMEBoundary_79a945e87ba858f448c98d77b4a80ffb5d7e70ea4b3491dd--
```

App.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging
           logEntireMessage="true"
           logMalformedMessages="false"
           logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
           logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
           maxMessagesToLog="3000"
           maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
    </diagnostics>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://xxxxxxx/ESARWS/CORETransactionService"
        behaviorConfiguration="endpointCredentialBehavior" binding="customBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="esar" contract="ESAR.CORETransaction"
        name="CoreSoapPort">
        <identity>
          <dns value="xxxxxxxx" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
   <behaviors>
     <endpointBehaviors>  
        <behavior name="endpointCredentialBehavior"> 
          <clientCredentials>  
            <clientCertificate findValue="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                               storeLocation="CurrentUser"
                               storeName="My"
                               x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>

           <serviceCertificate>
              <defaultCertificate findValue="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                               storeLocation="CurrentUser"
                               storeName="AddressBook"
                               x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />   
           </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>  
        </behavior>  
     </endpointBehaviors>  
  </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="esar">
          <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic128" authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"
            requireDerivedKeys="false" includeTimestamp="true" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" />
          <mtomMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
            messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          </mtomMessageEncoding>
          <httpsTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>


</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: can you share your proxy config file?

Comment: @FrancescoB. I updated my post with the app.config file.

Comment: also, your c# code?

Comment: The C# just calls a function in the proxy file. I think the issue is that I need to create my own custom encoder which I'm having issues with. .

Comment: Maybe. The strange thing is that it looks like the service response is MTOM actually.

Comment: I just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175231/wcf-error-creating-reader-for-mtom-message. Do you have experience creating custom encoders?

Comment: Yep I read that, and no experience with custom encoders...

Comment: Let me guess, govt. java based server?

Comment: From my limited understanding of this problem. 

Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/1/636579161448284066>

Is tripping up the WCF MTOM decoding, because it expect XOP. The first attachment in your response is okay, but the second one seems off.

Comment: Yeah it was a govt. java server.  I ended up creating a JavaClient that called the web service.